# Xamarin Android Dropdown menu/list

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, menu, xamarin

Is it possible to have a menu like this ( http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-d1pt2GTOZ-I/UjxbCVF-rlI/AAAAAAABGPc/Ed43IyMjGSo/s320/android-spinner-style-01.PNG ) in xamarin? I tried following a guide and tutorials, also I tried writing code with any help but I can obtain the same result, this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuY1i.png. It will return a pop-up with list.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In xamarin it is advised to use pickers to accomplish the dropdownlist behavior, checkout: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Picker/